# How to loop Dictionary<IEnumerable<string>, Dictionary<IEnumerable<decimal>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-4.0

class:

```
class myClass
{
    public int processId { get; set; }
    public string measurement { get; set; }
    public decimal measurementValue { get; set; }
    public string otherText { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
List<myClass> myClasses = new List<myClass> {
    new myClass { processId=1, measurement="height", measurementValue=10,otherText="312312" },
    new myClass { processId=1, measurement="length", measurementValue=11 ,otherText="312312"},
    new myClass { processId=1, measurement="width", measurementValue=12 ,otherText="312312"},
    new myClass { processId=2, measurement="height", measurementValue=20 ,otherText="312312"},
    new myClass { processId=2, measurement="length", measurementValue=21 ,otherText="312312"},
    new myClass { processId=2, measurement="width", measurementValue=22 ,otherText="312312"}
};

var groups = myClasses
    .GroupBy(o => o.processId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Select(x => x.measurement), g => g.Select(x => x.measurementValue));
```

`groups` is `Dictionary<IEnumerable<string>, Dictionary<IEnumerable<decimal>>`

How do I loop group in groups for all the key and value? I failed to figure it out.

```
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    //????
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to make an IEnumerable<string> as a key of a dictionary?

Comment: @CodeNotFound it's generate by the linq

Comment: It is generated by Linq because of you => `.ToDictionary(g => g.Select(x => x.measurement), ...)`. Usually we do this => `.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result `groups` object does not look logical to me. This dictionary make it easy to loop and it also seems to be more logical:

```
var groups = myClasses
    .GroupBy(o => o.processId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => new {Measurement = x.measurement, Value = x.measurementValue}));
```

Then looping and logging over groups:

```
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {"\t" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine + "\t\t\t\t", item.Value.Select(i => $"{nameof(i.Measurement)}:{i.Measurement},{nameof(i.Value)}:{i.Value}"))}");
}
```

will produce result:

```
Key: 1, Value:  Measurement:height,Value:10
                Measurement:length,Value:11
                Measurement:width,Value:12 
Key: 2, Value:  Measurement:height,Value:20
                Measurement:length,Value:21
                Measurement:width,Value:22
```